# How can I scale a web site to fit iPhone/iPad/Android Phone/Android tablet screens?

Tags: html

I am using this viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

However, the iPhone/iPad/Android devices the page comes out much larger than the screen.  I can only see the top left corner of the site.  My web site is 900px wide.

Next I changed viewport to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Now on the iPhone and maybe iPad it comes out okay with the content zoomed out so that it is filling the screen.  I'm not sure about the iPad since I don't have one of those to test with.  On Android devices this change did nothing.

What is the correct way to set view port so that a site fills the browser width?

Comment: Have a look at [Guidlines for Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/). Perhaps it might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to your second example. This is Android specific and works with `width=device-width` to tell the device that you want the page to be scaled to fit at all device resolutions.

Comment: Thank you I will try this.  For now I just took that viewport meta tag out entirely and Safari/Chrome appear to be able to handle the page the way I wanted them to.  Perhaps of case of trying to be too fancy on my part...